# How to use `Option<MyStruct>` on format?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use an Option of a `Method` on `format!`

```
/// Converts a method into a `&str`.
impl<'a> From<&'a Method> for &'a str {
    fn from(v: &'a Method) -> Self {
        match v {
            Method::Describe => "DESCRIBE",
            Method::GetParameter => "GET_PARAMETER",
            Method::Options => "OPTIONS",
            Method::Pause => "PAUSE",
            Method::Play => "PLAY",
            Method::PlayNotify => "PLAY_NOTIFY",
            Method::Redirect => "REDIRECT",
            Method::Setup => "SETUP",
            Method::SetParameter => "SET_PARAMETER",
            Method::Teardown => "TEARDOWN",
            Method::Extension(ref v) => v,
        }
    }
}
```

How do I use a `Option<Method>` in `format!`? I don't want to use `unwrap`, I want it to be empty in case there's no `Method`

I guess it's something like this:

```
let method = `Some(Method::Describe);
let method = match method {
    Some(method) => method.something,
    None => ""
};
```

Comment: `method.map(|m| m.something).unwrap_or("");`

Comment: Where's the `format!`?

Comment: If you want to have this display as such when used in a formatting macro, maybe you want to implement an `std::fmt` trait, such as [`std::fmt::Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html). My apologies if this is not what you meant by "on format".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this case you can use [map_or_else](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or_else)

So what you have would looks something like this?

```
let method = Some(Method::Describe);
let method = method.map_or_else(|| String::default(), |m| m.something);
```